# Nested jQuery Accordion miscalculates height

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-plugins

please guide me.

The setup:
 I am making a website using Jquery UI. The layout is as follows:
3 Jquery UI tabs on the top, when clicked, swaps content on the page based on iframes.
the 3rd tab displays a page which has a Jquery accordion.

The problem: When I click on the 3rd tab, accordian gets displayed, but the height of the content is JUST ONE LINE :( (so I am not at all able to see or read any content in the accordion). The height of contents is perfectly displayed if I open survey.html, but is just one line if I open it through index.html (nested call).

What I already tried: I read up online and came to know that may be I have to initialize the accordion widget first and then the tabs, since apparently the height of the accordian is getting miscalculated when the page loads. I tried a few things, but could not figure anything out, since I am a newbie. Please suggest some solutions.

The calling sequence:
The file index.html has the code for tabs. This file, has tab3 when clicked on opens another page (survey.html) inside the iframe which has the accordian in it.

The code:

```
Index.html CODE:
<head>
      <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
        $("#static-tabbed-panel-div").tabs();
    });
     </script> 
</head>

survey.html code:
<head>
<script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();


        });
</script>
```

Please advise.

What can I do to load the accordion before everything else or to adjust the height of the accordion contents on startup so that I can see it correctly?